# Spark scala - calculating dynamic timestamp interval

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

have dataframe with a timestamp column (timestamp type) called "maxTmstmp" and another column with hours, represented as integers called "WindowHours". **I would like to dynamically subtract timestamp and integer columns to get lower timestamp**.

My data and desired effect ("minTmstmp" column):

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|WindowHours|          maxTmstmp|          minTmstmp|
|           |                   |(maxTmstmp - Hours)|
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|          1|2016-01-01 23:00:00|2016-01-01 22:00:00|
|          2|2016-03-01 12:00:00|2016-03-01 10:00:00|
|          8|2016-03-05 20:00:00|2016-03-05 12:00:00|
|         24|2016-04-12 11:00:00|2016-04-11 11:00:00|
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+

 root
     |-- WindowHours: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- maxTmstmp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I have already found an expressions with hours interval solution, but it isn't dynamic. Code below doesn't work as intended.

```
standards.
      .withColumn("minTmstmp", $"maxTmstmp" - expr("INTERVAL 10 HOURS"))
      .show()
```

Operate on Spark 2.4 and scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way would be to convert `maxTmstmp` to [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), subtract the value of `WindowHours` in seconds from it, and convert the result back to Spark `Timestamp`, as shown below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-01-01 23:00:00")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-01 12:00:00")),
  (8, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-05 20:00:00")),
  (24, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-04-12 11:00:00"))
).toDF("WindowHours", "maxTmstmp")

df.withColumn("minTmstmp",
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"maxTmstmp") - ($"WindowHours" * 3600))
  ).show
// +-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
// |WindowHours|          maxTmstmp|          minTmstmp|
// +-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
// |          1|2016-01-01 23:00:00|2016-01-01 22:00:00|
// |          2|2016-03-01 12:00:00|2016-03-01 10:00:00|
// |          8|2016-03-05 20:00:00|2016-03-05 12:00:00|
// |         24|2016-04-12 11:00:00|2016-04-11 11:00:00|
// +-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Bellissimo! If i were able to give three thumbs up I would do that. Thanks a million, Leo C.